# Taking an existing customer product inventory list and creating bundles out of the products

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, relational-division

I'm working on SQL Server 2019 and have a problem I am trying to solve which I can best describe as "bundling" - the end result is a significantly shrunken dataset and fewer inventory items to keep track of.
Here is a quick example of the dataset:

| Account ID | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 10 |
| 1000 | 20 |
| 1000 | 30 |
| 1001 | 10 |
| 1001 | 20 |
| 1001 | 30 |
| 1001 | 50 |
| 1001 | 60 |
| 1001 | 70 |
| 1002 | 50 |
| 1002 | 60 |
| 1002 | 70 |
| 1003 | 80 |
| 1004 | 10 |
| 1004 | 20 |
| 1004 | 80 |

I created a new table which the "bundles" reside in as a reference table:

| Bundle ID | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 60 |
| 2 | 70 |
| 3 | 80 |

Quick note: In order for a bundle to be present on a given Account ID, ALL Product IDs within the bundle must be present.
My goal is to have this sort of output:

| Account ID | Bundle ID | # of Products outside Bundles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 0 |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 |
| 1001 | 2 | 0 |
| 1002 | 2 | 0 |
| 1003 | 3 | 0 |
| 1004 | 3 | 2 |

I expect to be eliminating/reviewing any outliers in the result set, i.e. Account IDs which have a number in the third column =/ 0

Initially I was just trying to use cases before making the actual table that the Bundles reside in, and then opted to put the product selection inside of a CTE.
My second approach was to string together every product name (another column part of the first table, names are distinct) and associate the extended string listing every single product the account owns as a new column within the CTE. Then, if the Account ID hits every single qualifier (i.e. PRODUCTSTRING LIKE 'Product1' AND PRODUCTSTRING LIKE 'Product2' . . . ) then it fulfills the case. This approach feels shaky at best and at worst like it will just give incorrect results for me unknowingly.

The only other approach that I can think of thus far is to count the number of unique products an Account ID has and match it to the count of unique products of a bundle, and then run cases based off of that, but even that feels like it will become extremely bulky very quickly.

The Account ID/Product ID view I'm working off of has around 1300 rows.
Could anyone point me in the direction of either an approach I have not considered or a tool I am missing?

Comment: I have no idea what your logic is for why account id 1004 has 3 products outside bundles... all its products seem like they should be in a bundle.

Comment: @DaleK, You are correct - I typo'd when converting to a richtext formatting. Thank you for the edits to my formatting and also for that catch - I will modify the example for Account ID 1004 to exclude Product ID 40.

Comment: My definition of the bundle is also that it must include ALL of the products for it to a bundle, which is something I didn't think of clarifying. Will add that to the body.

Comment: I still don't understand, account id 1001 is split across bundles 1 & 2 to cover all its products, why can't 1004 do the same? How do you which bundles to check for a given account id?

Comment: @DaleK The bundles should be applied the same for every account ID. Account 1004 has Product ID 10, 20, and 80, therefore it only gets Bundle ID 3 applied since that is the only group for which Account 1004 has ALL of the necessary Product IDs.

Comment: OK, seems unusual logic. But please show us your attempt to accomplish the result.

Comment: @DaleK it's common in some fields, for example when you have a combination discount (Buy 2 pay for 1), you want to find which products can be combined in which discount groups. But usually there can be multiple possible combos. What's the "tiebreak" criteria, ie. which case do you want to optimize for? Least/most number of possible bundles, least products left?

Comment: @DaleK I edited the body to explain the method of my second attempt.

Comment: We want to *see* it, text descriptions do not work well for data or code.

Comment: @siggemannen Yup - similar to a car insurance bundle is the first example that came to my mind, hence the word choice of "bundle".
Ideally there would be no accounts that do not have any bundles, so I am trying to get a result set that contains the MOST bundles possible.

Comment: (1) Can an account require more than one of a particular product? For example can an account require one of product 10, three of 20, and two of 30? (2) Can a product be a part of more than one bundle? For example, can one bundle include products 91 and 92, while another bundle includes products 91 and 93?. ... While I think we could construct a query to select eligible bundles and even prioritize the largest bundle, I think a general solution to select multiple bundles would require an iterative approach or a very complex recursive CTE. This might be better done in a procedural language.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This starts off as a kind of Relational Division With Remainder problem. You are missing the `Account` and `Bundle` tables, which store the unique values respectively, I have assumed these exist.

However, this is going to be extremely difficult to get what you want, especially given how poorly defined the problem is.

If you wanted to know just how many `ProductsRemaining` there are after applying a single `Bundle`, you can do as follows:

- Cross-join `Account` with `Bundle`
- Then, within an `APPLY`...
- ... take the `AccountProduct` for that `Account`...
- ... and the `BundleProduct` for that `Bundle`...
- ... and full-join them.
- Remove anything which has a missing `AccountProduct`, ie there exists a `BundleProduct` with no matching `AccountProduct`.
- Take the count of `AccountProduct` with no `BundleProduct`.

```sql
SELECT
  a.Id AS AccountId,
  b.Id AS BundleId,
  bp.*
FROM Account a
CROSS JOIN Bundle b
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) - COUNT(bp.ProductId) AS ProductsRemaining, COUNT(*) - COUNT(ap.ProductId) ap, count(*) c
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM AccountProduct ap
        WHERE ap.AccountId = a.Id
    ) ap
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM BundleProduct bp
        WHERE bp.BundleId = b.Id
    ) bp ON bp.ProductId = ap.ProductId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(ap.ProductId)  -- no missing products
) bp;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/RZvXY2Nh)

The problems start when, judging by your comments, you want to be able to take any possible combination of `Bundle` to make up the products, but we don't necessarily know which combination. There may be multiple possible combinations, some may be contradictory. You may need a combinatorics approach in some procedural language, trying every possible combnation of bundles.

For example, what happens if you put together one bundle which contains products `1, 2` and another containing `2, 3`, is that a valid combination for an account which has products `1, 2, 3`?